# htaccess, formatted query string and facebook links

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!(mk=[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|id=[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$).*$
RewriteRule ^view.php$ https://www.example.com/view.php? [L,R=301]
```

all works fine:

```
1) non-www > www and http>https redirects... 
2) Checking of values of query parameters "id" and "mk", 
whether they are well formatted or not according the to following requirements below:

"id" range: 1-9999 (without leading "0" from 1 to 9999)
"id": always lowercase, no "Id" or "ID" or "iD"
```

and

```
"mk" range: 1-99 (without leading "0" from 1 to 99)
"mk": always lowercase, no "Mk" or "MK" or "mK"
```

if "id"and "mk" values do not meet those rules (example id=qwe), then I drop abnormal query string and redirected it to general view.php url:

```
 https://www.example.com/view.php
```

The only problem I am facing is Facebook links to my site, they have the following structure which I want to keep:

```
https://www.example.com/view.php?id=123&fbclid=IwAR05VGnAct....
```

My htaccess drops the whole query string, because it thinks id=123&xxxx is already abnormally formatted query, so instead of going to particular page:

```
view.php?id=123
```

it goes to:

```
view.php
```

which is not good, because it is different content.

So, the **QUESTION** is how to make exception from query string normalization rules for Facebook links i.e. not to drop:

```
?id=123&fbclid=IwAR05VGnAct....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!(mk=[1-9]\d?|id=[1-9]\d{0,3})(&|$)).
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

This will rightly consider `&` as termination of `id` or `mk` parameters thus will allow `id=123&fbclid=IwAR05VGnAct` as query string.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I wanted to have, many thanks!